# Android Studio sharing custom view image via intent not working

Tags: java, android, canvas, share, custom-view

I am having some trouble trying to share a custom view in one of my activities via social media (Facebook etc...) by button click, however when I press the button nothing happens and Logcat is not showing any errors. The custom view is of a canvas drawing. Below is my code:

```
public class GraphActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DrawGraphTest drawGraphTest;

    private Button shareImage;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_graph);
        drawGraphTest = (DrawGraphTest)findViewById(R.id.drawGraphTest);

        shareImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShare);
        shareImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                share(drawGraphTest);
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetWorldReadable")
    public void share(View view){
        Bitmap bitmap =getBitmapFromView(drawGraphTest);
        try {
            File file = new File(this.getExternalCacheDir(),"myImage.png");
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
            file.setReadable(true, false);
            final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
            intent.setType("image/png");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share image via"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        Drawable bgDrawable =view.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable!=null) {
            //has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        }   else{
            //does not have background drawable, then draw white background on the canvas
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        view.draw(canvas);
        return returnedBitmap;
    }

}
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".GraphActivity">

    <g.myPackage.DrawGraphTest
        android:id="@+id/drawGraphTest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnShare"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.982" />
```

I have also enabled these permissions in my Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

On the button click, Logcat Verbose shows:

```
2019-03-21 04:30:26.147 19176-19176/g.companieshouse.companieshouse D/errortag1: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/g.companieshouse.companieshouse/cache/companieshouse.png exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
```

For reference, the code that I am trying to implement is in the link below and as I am new to Android Studio I am struggling to see where I went wrong in my implementation and could really use some help! The only difference that I can see is that in the link they are sharing an Image View whereas I am sharing a custom view.

https://www.logicchip.com/share-image-without-saving/

Comment: Remove the try-catch block and check which error occurred.

Comment: @Aslam Hossin So I removed the try catch block and it says "Unhandled exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException" when I highlight "new FileOutputStream(file)" and also "fOut.flush()" says "Unhandled exception java.io.IOException".

Comment: @Aslam Hossin I updated the post to show the stacktrace on the button clicked in Logcat under Verbose, I don't know if this will help at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception that is thrown when an application exposes a **file://** Uri to another app.

This exposure is discouraged since the receiving app may not have access to the shared path. For example, the receiving app may not have requested the **Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** runtime permission or the platform may be sharing the Uri across user profile boundaries.

Instead, apps should use **content://** Uris so the platform can extend temporary permission for the receiving app to access the resource.

This is only thrown for applications targeting Build.VERSION_CODES#N or higher. Applications targeting earlier SDK versions are allowed to share **file://** **Uri**, but it's strongly discouraged.

Possible solution : [android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/test.txt exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed)

Comment: thank you for pointing me in the right direction with your link. Managed to find a solution!

Answer (score 0):

if android version > m, get URI must through FileProvider， like this

```
fun getUri(file: File): Uri? {
     try {
         return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
         FileProvider.getUriForFile(MyApp.instance, MyApp.instance.packageName, file)
     } else {
         Uri.fromFile(file)
     }
     } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
     }
     return null
}
```